# Tracking attribution on the WhatsApp Business API?

Tags: whatsapp

The WhatsApp Business API does not have a `ref` parameter (like Messenger does, for instance) which allows the receiving application to know where a given WhatsApp user came from.

Conversations with a business over WhatsApp are usually initiated via a link -- and the only fields that can be supplied to the `wa.me` link are the `number` and `text` fields ([source](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/)).

Is there a way that I can get around this restriction, and add a `ref` parameter (e.g. `ref=google-ad`) to the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a [detailed post on encoding params into the WhatsApp link](https://yaz.in/p/tracking-where-whatsapp-users-came-from/) that address this specific question.

There's no official solution, but the writer has a smart hack: using non-printable characters to encode the DeviceID (or ref param, in your case) to the `text` parameter.

Code for encoding/decoding the param is reproduced below, but I recommend [reading the article](https://yaz.in/p/tracking-where-whatsapp-users-came-from/) for all the pertinent details:

```
# This class handles encoding and decoding of non printable characters
# into strings

class NonPrintableCoder
  NON_PRINTABLES = %W(\u200a \u200b \u200c \u200d \u200e)

  class << self
    def encode(num)
      base = NON_PRINTABLES.length
      output = ""

      while(num > 0) do
        output = NON_PRINTABLES[num % base] + output # MSB -> LSB
        num /= base
      end

      output
    end

    def decode(str)
      base = NON_PRINTABLES.length
      output = 0

      str.length.times do |i|
        chr = str[str.length - i - 1]
        output += NON_PRINTABLES.index(chr) * base ** i
      end

      output
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
# Generate link (encode '12345' into text string)
"https://wa.me/..?text=" + NonPrintableCoder.encode(12345) + "hi there!"

# Incoming webhook (extract '12345' from text string)
non_printables = msg.split("").filter do |char|
  char.in? NonPrintableCoder::NON_PRINTABLES
end
NonPrintableCoder.decode(non_printables) # => 12345
```